# Achieving absolute ordering on JPA event-entities

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, jpa, event-sourcing

I try to define immutable Event-Entites (Event Sourcing) using Java JPA/Hibernate and want those events to have an absolute ordering that already is defined right after object-creation, before any persistence has taken place (no distributed setup where one would need consensus)

We are using automatic auditing properties using @CreatedDate but I crossed that off my list since this is only populated during persistence.

I can think of 2 options:

1. using a global database-sequence that is queried during object-creation
2. `Long ordering = System.nanoTime()`

any advice/idea appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> want those events to have an absolute ordering that already is defined
>   right after object-creation

1. The simpliest solution is like:

   ```
   public class SomeEntity {
       private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
   }
   ```

   Of course it is possible that two objects will be created simultaneously and will have the same date, but it might be extremely hard to get.
2. A bit more complex - ordered by id if dates are equal and both objects are persisted. There may be indeterminacy if some of objects is not persisted yet, but if both are persisted - strict order is guaranteed:

   ```
   public class SomeEntity implements Comparable<SomeEntity> {

       private Long id;

       private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();

       @Override
       public int compareTo(SomeEntity o) {
           int result = createdAt.compareTo(o.createdAt);
           if (result == 0) {
               if (id != null && o.id != null) {
                   result = id.compareTo(o.id);
               } else if (id != null) {
                   result = 1;
               } else if (o.id != null) {
                   result = -1;
               }
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The most complex option but strict ordering is guaranteed: you can create counter service in your JVM and create events through factory, that will use that counter during event creation.

   ```
   public class CounterService {
       AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
       public int getNext() {
           return counter.incrementAndGet();
       }
   }

   public class SomeEntityFactory {
       private CounterService counterService;

       public SomeEntity create() {
           return new SomeEntity(counterService.getNext());
       }
   }

   public class SomeEntity {
       private int order;

       SomeEntity(int order) {
           this.order = order;
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course, this is example only, counter service might return BigInteger and be a web service, for instance. Or you can use a database sequence like a counter.

Comment: i am hesistant to use the wall-clock time (`LocalDateTime.now()`).

Comment: the `CounterService` would always start from 0, so this would need to be persistant. then one could use a database-sequence right-away. isnt it?

Comment: There is a plenty of options with counter, I wrote it just for example. DB sequence is just another representation of that approach. Please, clerify for me why are you hesistant to use `LocalDateTime`? I know that there are some aspects you need to pay attention to, e.g. timezones, but it can be solved. What   precision do you need?

Comment: @hotzen I changed code in the second solution a little.

Comment: i am hesistant because of time skew (even if ntp)

Comment: @hotzen thus, counter is your option.